# rails to_json including an association of attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class that contains multiple rails models as attr_accessors, I am storing rails models in table, item and user

```
class News
 attr_accessor :table, :item, :user
end
```

I have an `array of News` objects that I want to convert to JSON `feeds.to_json`

table model has a association called org, how do I include the org association?

the following do not work

```
feeds.to_json(:include => [:org])
feeds.to_json(:methods => [:org])
feeds.to_json(:include => {:table => { :include => [:org] }})
```

Comment: Did you try feeds.to_json(:include => [:orgs]) which version of rails are you using ?

Comment: rails 3.2 and I did figure it out. has to override table as_json to include org and then call feeds.to_json(:include => :table)